# How to adjust the rotated box of the table to the center

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, tabularx, rotating, texniccenter

```
\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\caption{Units for Magnetic Properties}
\label{tablsssss}
\centering
%\bfseries
\begin{tabular}{|p{4pt}|p{40pt}|p{80pt}|p{100pt}|p{200pt}|p{10pt}|}
\hline
\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\raisebox{-5pt}{year}} &  Ref &  Alg & Goal & Appr  &   Test  \\
\hline
\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\raisebox{-5pt}{2019}}& 33&  39.66&  39.66&  39.5&65 \\
\cline{2-6}
 &Moy Pages cibles & 25.66&  62&  100&  33 \\
 \cline{2-6}
 &Moy Pages cibles & 25.66&  62&  100&  33 \\
 \cline{2-6}
 &Moy Pages cibles & 25.66&  62&  100&  33 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}\hspace*{-2cm}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}
```

[image]

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/501271/134144

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with multirow package. Please consider the following code:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{rotating,multirow}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\caption{Units for Magnetic Properties}
\label{tablsssss}
\centering
%\bfseries
\begin{tabular}{|c|p{60pt}|p{80pt}|p{40pt}|p{40pt}|p{14pt}|}
\hline
\rotatebox[]{90}{year} &  Ref &  Alg & Goal & Appr  &   Test  \\
\hline
\multirow{7}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{2019}}& 33&  39.66&  39.66&  39.5&65 \\
\cline{2-6}
 &Moy Pages cibles & 25.66&  62&  100&  33 \\
 \cline{2-6}
 &Moy Pages cibles & 25.66&  62&  100&  33 \\
 \cline{2-6}
 &Moy Pages cibles & 25.66&  62&  100&  33 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

This is the result:

[image]