# How do I insert sub-bullets in a table environment?

Tags: tables, bullets

I am having difficulty making bulleted points in tables using TeXMaker.

This is a sample of the table I am working on.

This is moreorless what it looks like
[image: intended table]

-I want to be able to **introduce sub-bullets but I don't know how (if possible, while maintaining the `$\RHD$` (or right hand diamond; see figure above) symbol**);

-**Tried itemize to introduce these sub-bullets unsuccessfully**;

-**Even a simple itemize does not compile** for some reason and I get a number of error messages;

*Here is where I would like help*:

-I would like to ***understand why itemize does not work below*** and ***how I might introduce sub-bullets using the RHD symbol***;

Sample of the code

***Temporary bit (trying to implement Mico's answer here.)***

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper, twoside]{article}

\usepackage{times}
\linespread{1.5}
\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{
 a4paper,
 left=1in,
 right=1in,
 top=1in,
 bottom=1in
 }
\usepackage{setspace} % allows you to change spacing inside document - for e.g for tables, relevant for tables
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb} % AMS symbols
\usepackage{wasysym} % more symbols - \RHD (arrow)
\usepackage{pifont} % for dingbat symbols 
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}% Pretty tables
\newcommand{\tabitem}{~~\llap{\textbullet}~~}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
  \newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}} 
\usepackage{sectsty} % want sigle spacing in subheadings and headings 
\allsectionsfont{\singlespacing}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{float}

% To get landscape in between pages
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{parskip} % allows space between paragraphs
\setlength{\parindent}{3em} % sets indentation of paragraph
\setlength{\parskip}{0em} % allows space between paragraphs 
\usepackage{indentfirst}

\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{enumitem, ragged2e,array}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}

% 'btr': short for 'black triangle right'
\newlist{btr}{itemize}{2} % setup for 2 list levels
% elements common to both level-l and level-2 lists:
\setlist[btr]{nosep, left=0pt,
              before=\begin{minipage}{\linewidth},
              after =\end{minipage}}
% level-1 and level-2 items differ (only) in size of \blacktriangleright symbol:
\setlist[btr,1]{label=$\scriptstyle\blacktriangleright$}
\setlist[btr,2]{label=$\vcenter{\hbox{$\scriptscriptstyle\blacktriangleright$}}$}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{spacing}{1}
\begin{longtable}{p{1.5in}p{1in}p{2in}p{1.5in}p{2.5in}}

\toprule
Study & Country & Characteristic/Component & Methodology & Findings\\ 
\midrule
\endfirsthead
\toprule
Study & Country & Characteristic/Component & Methodology & Findings\\ 
\midrule
\endhead % all the lines above this will be repeated on every page

\bottomrule % puts bottomrule @ end of table on every page
\endfoot

\bottomrule % puts bottomrule @ end of final page 
\endlastfoot

sample study name
&
sample country
&
\begin{tabular}{p{2in}}
$\RHD$ sample intervention;\\
$\RHD$ sample methodology.
\end{tabular}
&
\begin{tabular{@{}p{\linewidth}@{}}
%\begin{tabular}{p{1.5in}}
\begin{btr}
\item sample methodologies
    \begin{btr}
    \item hello
    \end{btr}
\end{btr}
\end{tabular}
&
\begin{tabular}{p{2.5in}}
$\RHD$ sample findings;\\
$\RHD$ finding 2;\\
$\RHD$ finding 3;\\
\end{tabular}\\
\midrule
\addlinespace
\end{longtable}
\end{spacing}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

(I know that this contains a very long list of packages; this is a joint project with someone else and I removed as many excess packages as I could ... there may be more nonessential packages but was not sure which these were. Also, in case it is helpful, the original table spans 10+ pages)

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper, twoside]{article}

\usepackage{times}
\linespread{1.5}
\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{
 a4paper,
 left=1in,
 right=1in,
 top=1in,
 bottom=1in
 }
\usepackage{setspace} % allows you to change spacing inside document - for e.g for tables, relevant for tables
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb} % AMS symbols
\usepackage{wasysym} % more symbols - \RHD (arrow)
\usepackage{pifont} % for dingbat symbols 
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}% Pretty tables
\newcommand{\tabitem}{~~\llap{\textbullet}~~}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
  \newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}} 
\usepackage{sectsty} % want sigle spacing in subheadings and headings 
\allsectionsfont{\singlespacing}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{float}

% To get landscape in between pages
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{parskip} % allows space between paragraphs
\setlength{\parindent}{3em} % sets indentation of paragraph
\setlength{\parskip}{0em} % allows space between paragraphs 
\usepackage{indentfirst}

\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{spacing}{1}
\begin{longtable}{p{1.5in}p{1in}p{2in}p{1.5in}p{2.5in}}

\toprule
Study & Country & Characteristic/Component & Methodology & Findings\\ 
\midrule
\endfirsthead
\toprule
Study & Country & Characteristic/Component & Methodology & Findings\\ 
\midrule
\endhead % all the lines above this will be repeated on every page

\bottomrule % puts bottomrule @ end of table on every page
\endfoot

\bottomrule % puts bottomrule @ end of final page 
\endlastfoot

sample study name
&
sample country
&
\begin{tabular}{p{2in}}
$\RHD$ sample intervention;\\
$\RHD$ sample methodology.
\end{tabular}
&
\begin{tabular}{p{1.5in}}
\begin{itemize}
\item sample methodologies; \\
\end{itemize}
\end{tabular}
&
\begin{tabular}{p{2.5in}}
$\RHD$ sample findings;\\
$\RHD$ finding 2;\\
$\RHD$ finding 3;\\
\end{tabular}\\
\midrule
\addlinespace

\end{longtable}
\end{spacing}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

(*A section of the table would ideally look like either of these (with the arrow representing the `$\RHD$`; couldn't find it on word)*):

[image: v1]
[image]

Thank you for taking the time to read this. Am grateful for any help and guidance on this.

Comment: Please give a fully compilable code.

Comment: you have not provided a test document nor shown the error message but I would assume the undefined command was \RHD as you do not show any definition for that.

Comment: See also: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/501280/134144

Comment: Thank you for the feedback ... @DavidCarlisle, is a test document the same as a fully compilable code?

Comment: @TheEconomist - An *ideal* test document (a) is compilable, (b) gives rises to the issue you want to fix, and (c) is minimal in the sense that it doesn't  contain code that's not needed to satisfy (a) and (b). It's sometimes not easy to generate such a test document. Do peruse the posting [I've just been asked to write a minimal working example (MWE), what is that](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5001), though, to learn more about what constitutes a *useful* test document.

Comment: @TheEconomist yes basically somthing that makes your question understandable:-) You have posted some fragments of code but we can't run them but they use a command `\RHD` that I don't recognise and you say you had an undefined command error but don't say which command was undefined, so all I can do is guess that it is `\RHD` but that is unrelated to your question about itemize so the question is not really answerable. (Although Mico has  taken a guess:-)

Comment: I have updated the MWE so that it is compilable ... itemize does not run within the method I have set up above for some reason ... would be grateful for your thoughts as to why this might be...

Comment: You write, "itemize does not run within the method I have set up above for some reason". The reason is the needless, spurious, and pointless `\\` directive after `sample methodologies;`.

Comment: It worked! I spent far too long trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(augmented the answer by a second-level "btr" itemize-like environment per the OP's request.)

Rather than set up lots of individual tabular environments and create the itemized lists by hand, I suggest you employ the machinery of `enumitem` package, as is done below, to create two levels of a bespoke itemize-like list environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry} % set page parameters suitably
\usepackage{longtable,booktabs}
\usepackage{enumitem,ragged2e,array} % new
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}
\usepackage{amssymb} % for "\blacktriangleright" macro

% 'btr': short for 'black triangle right'
\newlist{btr}{itemize}{2} % setup for 2 list levels
% elements common to both level-l and level-2 lists:
\setlist[btr]{nosep, left=0pt,
              before=\begin{minipage}{\linewidth},
              after =\end{minipage}}
% level-1 and level-2 items differ (only) in size of \blacktriangleright symbol:
\setlist[btr,1]{label=$\scriptstyle\blacktriangleright$}
\setlist[btr,2]{label=$\vcenter{\hbox{$\scriptscriptstyle\blacktriangleright$}}$}


\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{@{} P{0.85in} P{0.95in} P{1.5in} *{2}{P{1.25in}} @{}}
\toprule
Study & Country & Characteristic\slash Component & Methodology & Findings\\ 
\midrule
\endhead

\bottomrule
\endlastfoot

sample study name&
sample country&
\begin{btr}
\item sample intervention
\item sample methodology
\end{btr} &
\begin{btr}
\item sample methodology
  \begin{btr}
  \item Hello
  \item Byebye
  \end{btr}
\item sample methodology
\item sample methodology
\end{btr} &
\begin{btr}
\item sample findings;
\item finding 2;\\
\item finding 3;\\
\end{btr}
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum* to address the OP's latest follow-up. My ability to explain things must have deteriorated significantly of late, as the new code you posted does pretty much the *exact opposite* of what I thought I had recommended.

- If you use the bespoke `btr` list-like environments in a column of type `p`, there is *absolutely no need* to encase the `btr` material in a single-column `tabular` wrapper. Hence, do please replace

  ```
   \begin{tabular{@{}p{\linewidth}@{}}
   %\begin{tabular}{p{1.5in}}
   \begin{btr}
   \item sample methodologies
       \begin{btr}
       \item hello
       \end{btr}
   \end{btr}
   \end{tabular}
  ```

with

```
    \begin{btr}
    \item sample methodologies
        \begin{btr}
        \item hello
        \end{btr}
    \end{btr}
```

- What I *thought* I was telling you to do was: If, for some reason, you do *not* want to use the bespoke list-like environments, then by all means use single-column `tabular` environments to create something that looks like it could have been generated by a list-type environment. I was going by your question, "would it be possible to implement your solution within individual tabular environments?" I thought that this meant you were looking for an *alternative* to the `btr` approach. Was I mistaken?

Comment: +1 I like the idea of using `before=\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}, after =\end{minipage},`.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion!

Comment: Is it possible to sub-bullet with what you have suggested above? The sub-bullet would need to be slightly indented like I have shown with the last two images in my question ... I tried implementing it and indented a couple of the points but it did not result in a different output from what you have shown above.

Comment: @TheEconomist: Using `\newlist{btr}{itemize}{2}` and something like `\begin{btr}
  \item sample methodology
  \item sample methodology
  \begin{btr}
  \item subitem
  \end{btr}
  \item sample methodology
\end{btr} &` should give you correctly indented second level items.

Comment: @leandriis - Your suggestion will definitely work. I decided to go ahead and edit my answer to define both a 1st and a 2nd level list environment called "btr" -- mainly to get the opportunity to assign an even smaller black-triangle-right symbol to the 2nd-level items.

Comment: @TheEconomist - Please see the edits I applied to code. To get "sub-bullets", as you put it, it's necessary to define 2 levels, rather than just 1 level, of the `btr` environment. Incidentally, do note that the `btr` list environments will work both in- and outside `longtable` environments.

Comment: @Mico, would it be possible to implement your solution within individual tabular environments? Most of the work was done by my colleague and now we have 10+ page table that was generated using this method. It would be convenient if we could implement this itemize solution of yours within our existing individual tabular environment. I realize it may not be efficient but it would be quickest for completing our work... I updated my MWE and made it complete ... would be grateful for your thoughts on this ...

Comment: @Mico, on a less-important level, even when I implemented the code from your answer I got the following error ```! Package enumitem Error: left undefined.``` it still generates the output you show above but I'm wondering why this might be the case...

Comment: On a formatting level, how would you vary spacing more between the first bullet and its sub-bullet? (it is less than the spacing between sub-bullets and would like to increase if possible)

Comment: @TheEconomist - you ask, "I'm wondering why this might be the case." Sadly (but possibly not surprisingly), my psychic abilities are absolutely worthless. If you don't show the code that gives rise to the error messages, the odds that I will be able to somehow divine on my own what's going on are vanishingly small.

Comment: @TheEconomist - you ask, "how would you vary spacing more between the first bullet and its sub-bullet?" Please provide more information about what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @TheEconomist - you ask, " would it be possible to implement your solution within individual tabular environments?" The answer is yes. In fact, the tabular-related code in your updated MWE already answers your question. However, do please change both `\begin{tabular}{p{2in}}` and `\begin{tabular}{p{2.5in}}` to `\begin{tabular{@{}p{\linewidth}@{}}`.

Comment: Thanks for the help Mico! Will get back with clarifications and implement these too...

Comment: @Mico, thank you the solution works within individual tabular environments ... however when I add ```\begin{tabular{@{}p{\linewidth}@{}}``` instead of ```\begin{tabular}{p{2in}}```, it produces an error message and the bullets indent more. 
I have left the code in my original question under ***trying to implement Mico's solution*** ... would you know how to decrease the indent?